# Multiple php email issue

Tags: php, email

For my project I had to create a function that sends two email. One to the customer and the other to the a seller. Both emails will have different contents.

I wrote the two function using the standard PHP mail function as below.

```
            $to      = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
    $subject = 'xxxx';
    $message =  "hello"  
    $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Now, While testing the system on my own company's web server both emails seems to be sent and received. However, when I migrated the same system into an external server. only one email gets sent. primarily, the first email in the stack.

While I suspect the issue has something to do with the later server configuration, I am wondering where should I go next to debug this issue.

Comment: I don't see any code there that is sending two emails...

Comment: Have you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and gotten any errors/notices? Have you used any other debugging methods (such as e.g. examining the differences of both servers)?

Comment: It sounds like the seller's mail server is filtering the email as spam for some reason. If it works on your test server but not the external server, it's probably because the external server is in a block list, and has nothing to do with your script.

Comment: Is $headers set in code you didn't paste?  And, is it unset (or emptied) before you try to send the second email (also, I'm assuming in code you didn't paste)?  If not, you're appending $headers to an unset string, then possibly appending the same two $headers later on to a previously set $headers string.  Duplicate headers may not allow the message through on one server, while the other doesn't care.

Comment: For one thing and if this is your "actual code", you need to put a semi-colon here `$message =  "hello"` as in `$message =  "hello";` otherwise you won't like what PHP's gonna throw at you. Tell me that's a typo. And if so, edit your question with the appropriate change.

Comment: Clearly some piece of this is missing... `$headers` is always added to but never defined.

Comment: @quasivivo you might have a point there. let me look try to remove the concatenation.

Comment: Plus, remove the dot in `$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` as in `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` the first (`$headers`) doesn't take one and will also generate an error.

Comment: @quasivivo and Fred -ii- : yup that was the issue. thank you both

Comment: You're welcome. I posted something below which you're welcome to use, and may help you further in regards to using extra header information. @AlFredo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few things in your "posted" code that were missing.

A missing semi-colon at the end of `$message =  "hello"` (unless that was a typo/paste error?) and a dot in the first `$headers`

Also, not having a `From:` header attribute will surely result having the Email sent to and regarded as SPAM.

Having fixed those issues and added extra header information, the following code worked and did not end up in my SPAM, but the INBOX successfully.

```
<?php
$to      = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
$email = "email@example.com";
$subject = 'xxxx';
$message =  "hello";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

**Or with a success echo'ed message:**

```
<?php
$to      = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
$email = "email@example.com";
$subject = 'xxxx';
$message =  "hello";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
echo "Message sent.";
}

else{
echo "Something went wrong.";
}

?>
```

Visit the PHP.net website for more information on the `mail()` and `header()` functions.

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**